# Include category in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am querying my

```
$posts = new array("71", "10")

$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'Hardware',
  'post__in' => $posts,
));
```

I would like to also get back the category of my posts in the result.

Any suggestions how to include this in the above query?

Comment: no need to use the new array just use the array(71,10) instead of new array("71,"10"")

Comment: You can get your Post-Id, right? So is this not enough for you? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/

Comment: @evayly Thx for your reply! Is it possible to get the categories directly in the query, when I am using `post__in` and not write an extra function?

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the function `get_the_category($post_id)`. You need to pass post id:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $category = get_the_category($query->ID)

        // Contents of the queried post results go here.

    }
```

}